# AngularJS NG-Repeat Seems to Not Work on Array with Single Object

Tags: arrays, angularjs, object, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have found many posts about how ng-repeat does not play well with objects, and expects the data to be an array, but my data is an array, it just happens to have a single object(list2). I get list1 fine, and everything works perfect. According to everything that I have found, list2 should work. Anyone know why it doesn't?

Data coming from my factory:

```
(function(){
var Factory = function(){

    var model =  {
        list1: [
            {
                id: "1_1",
                type: "header",
                headerText: "1_1 Header",
                secondaryHeaderText: "",
                paragraphText: "1_1 Paragraph",
                image: ""
            },
            {
                id: "1_2",
                type: "header",
                headerText: "Header 1_2",
                secondaryHeaderText: "",
                paragraphText: "1_2 Paragraph",
                image: ""
            },
            {
                id: "1_3",
                type: "header",
                headerText: "1_3 Header1",
                secondaryHeaderText: "1_3 Header2",
                paragraphText: "",
                image: ""
            }
        ],
        list2: [
            {
                id: "2_1",
                type: "link",
                headerText: "2_1 Header",
                paragraphText: "2_1 Paragraph",
                linkText: "2_1 Link Text",
                image: ""
            }
        ]
    };

    var factory = {};

    factory.getList1 = function(){
        return model.list1;
    };

    factory.getList2 = function(){
        return model.list2;
    };

    return factory;
};
angular.module('designApp').factory('Factory', Factory);
}());
```

HMTL

```
<div>
    <!--works perfectly fine -->
    <div ng-repeat="item in list1" ng-include="'app/partial/list1.html'"></div>
</div>

<div>
     <div ng-repeat="item in list2" ng-include="'app/partial/list2.html'"></div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
(function(){
var Controller = function($scope, Factory){
    $scope.list1 = [];
    $scope.list2 = [];


function init(){
    $scope.list1 = Factory.getList1();
    $scope.list2 = Factory.getList2();
}

init();
};

Controller.$inject = ['$scope', 'Factory'];

angular.module('designApp')
    .controller('Controller', Controller);
}());
```

This is all that is in list2.html. Does not render any of the model data but renders the html tags, and throws no errors.

```
<h2>{{list2.headerText}}</h2>
<p>{{list2.paragraphText}}</p>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to replace

```
<h2>{{list2.headerText}}</h2>
<p>{{list2.paragraphText}}</p>
```

by

```
<h2>{{item.headerText}}</h2>
<p>{{item.paragraphText}}</p>
```

working plunkr:
https://plnkr.co/edit/FC5KPpOl7gsmfva63veq?p=preview

Comment: np, although i have to mention that i would not recommend you do use ng-repeat and ng-include together. it can vastly crush the performance on your app for medium and large data. see a blog entry here if you want:
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2738-using-ngrepeat-with-nginclude-hurts-performance-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: Great insight. I didn't realize this was happening. I will be looking into "component" directives to solve this issue. Found this for anyone who may come along, and want some reference into the solution:  https://www.airpair.com/angularjs/posts/component-based-angularjs-directives